# PHP OOP: Call to a member function on a non-object

Tags: php

I have created a user class with the following code:

```
  <?php
    require_once("database.php");
    class User {
        public $id;
        public $username;
        public $password;
        public $first_name;
        public $last_name;

        public static function find_all() {
            return self::find_by_sql("select * from users");
        }
        public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
            global $database;
            $result_array=self::find_by_sql("Select * from users where id={$id} limit 1");
            if (!empty($result_array)) {
                return array_shift($result_array);
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        public function find_by_sql($sql="") {
            global $database;
            $result_set=$database->query($sql);
            $object_array=array();
            while ($row=$database->fetch_array($result_set)) {
                $object_array[]=self::instantiate($row);
            }
                return $object_array;
        }
        public function full_name() {
            if (isset($this->first_name)&& isset($this->last_name)) {
        return $this->first_name." ".$this->lastname;
            } else {
                return "";
            }   
        }
        private static function instantiate($record) {
            $object=new self;
            $object->id=$record['id'];
            $object->username=$record['username'];
            $object->password=$record['password'];
            $object->first_name=$record['first_name'];
            $object->last_name=$record['last_name'];
            return $object; 
        }
    }
    ?>
```

When I try to execute the following code in the index.php

```
<?php
$user=User::find_by_id(1);
echo $user->full_name();
?>
```

I get the following error:

```
( ! ) Fatal error: Call to a member function full_name() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\imagepro\public\index.php on line 8
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0010  669408  {main}( )   ..\index.php:0
```

I don't understand why I am getting this error because I think the object has been instantiated and the error says that I am calling an object function from non-object.

Can there be a problem with my PHP settings as I am running this on a localhost. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 5):

It means that `$user` is not an object. Since `find_by_id()` can return `FALSE` (which is not an object), my guess is that's what's happening: There simply is no user with ID 1, so you get nothing (`FALSE` in this case), and you can't get object properties from `FALSE`.

To solve this, add some kind of check (`is_object($user)` or `$user !== FALSE`) before attempting to use it as an object.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (!empty($result_array)) {
                return array_shift($result_array);
            } else {
                return FALSE;
            }
```

means that `$user` can be either array or false - this all is not an object.

Comment: That's what I though as well, but it seems the OP is calling a lot of static function to generate an array of objects so the return value can be an object.